# Disable manual input for MUI TimePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I have a bit of a custom [`TimePicker`](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/time-picker/) provided from Material UI. I add an ability for the user to select only whole hours, such as 15:00, 16:00 etc. by clicking on a clock icon

What I want to achieve is to add same for manual input of the text field. For now user can manually add any valid time, for example 14:34, which is incorrect for my case

Can anyone help me?

Here is my `TimePicker`:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} locale={locale}>
    <TimePicker
        ampm={false}
        openTo="hours"
        views={['hours']}
        inputFormat="HH:mm"
        mask="__:__"
        value={dayStartValue}
        InputAdornmentProps={{
            position: 'start',
        }}
        components={{
            OpenPickerIcon: ClockFilledIcon,
        }}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
            setDayStartValue(newValue)
        }}
        renderInput={(params) =>
            <TextField
                {...params}
                helperText="Input start of Day time"
            />
            
        }
    />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control and validate the user's input when he clicks away from the time picker by using `onBlur` inside `InputProps`.

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { TimePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker";

export default function BasicTimePicker() {
  const [dayStartValue, setDayStartValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider
      dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
      locale={locale}
    >
      <TimePicker
        ampm={false}
        openTo="hours"
        views={["hours"]}
        inputFormat="HH:mm"
        mask="__:__"
        value={dayStartValue}
        InputAdornmentProps={{
          position: "start"
        }}
        components={{
            OpenPickerIcon: ClockFilledIcon,
        }}
        onChange={(newValue: Date, keyboardInputValue?: string) => {
          setDayStartValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} helperText="Input start of Day time" />
        )}
        InputProps={{
          onBlur: (
            e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement, Element>
          ) => {
            const newDate = new Date(dayStartValue);
            newDate.setMinutes(0);
            if (e.target.value && e.target.value.length === 5) {
              setDayStartValue(newDate);
            }
          }
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

For the validation we check the user input and if it's a valid Date (5 characters length), we create a new Date with that and set the minutes to 0.

[Code Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hour-time-picker-vcw834?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your input format and the mask to only accept whole hours like so:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <TimePicker
        ampm={false}
        openTo="hours"
        views={['hours']}
        inputFormat="HH:00"
        mask="__:00"
        value={value}
        InputAdornmentProps={{
            position: 'start',
        }}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue)
        }}
        renderInput={(params) =>
            <TextField
                {...params}
                helperText="Input start of Day time"
            />
            
        }
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-cohen-te8fxy?file=/demo.tsx)